# Smooth way to move big images with Jquery

Tags: jquery, performance, performance-testing

I have a series of photos like this:

I wanna to move it as fast as possible with jquery when I click on a next button. 
I'm trying this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function movePhotoCycle(next) {
     if (next) {
        // move the first photo at the end
        $(".slidephoto").first().clone().appendTo("#slidebox");
     } else {
        // move the last photo at the beginning

                ....
     }
};

  $("#next").click(function() {
    var boxleft = $("#slidebox").position().left;
         $("#slidebox").animate({
            left: boxleft - 1500
         }, 1500, function () { 
            $(".slidephoto").first().remove();
         });
        movePhotoCycle(true);
    return false;
});
});
```

It works actually but on my I5 computer is a little bit odd (not smooth enough). Framerate is under 30, sometimes less. May be because every image is about 915x390 . But is there a way to optimize the execution of this code in order to have a smooth animation ?

Comment: The animate function is set to animate over 1500ms? If you want it as fast as possible should this value not be smaller?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use [GSAP JS](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) instead of jQuery for animations if you need really fluid animations. GSAP will also take advantage of native hardware acceleration if available, which jQuery does not.

Check out [the speed test](http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html) if you need convincing.

There is a [jQuery plugin](http://www.greensock.com/jquery-gsap-plugin/) that will allow you to extend the jQuery `.animate()` function with GSAP so you don't need to change any of your code.

If you don't want the overhead of another library, then you can either try to optimize your jQuery animations (make sure the elements you are animating are absolutely positioned, for example) or use CSS transitions to animate the position properties of your elements, which will use native hardware acceleration in the browser if available. This has the disadvantage of not working at all on older browsers, and world badly on browsers where this is poorly implemented (e.g. mobile).